# How to fetch only the contents of Database using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch three columns from the MySql database. I am able to fetch the contents but this is not what I need. I need only the contents as a string array so that I can use them to populate list view in my java code.

The current response from my script is:

```
{  ["UID"]=>  string(1) "1"  ["UserName"]=>  string(7) "abc@123"  ["Subject"]=>  string(15) "My Android Post"}object(stdClass)#4 (3) {  ["UID"]=>  string(1) "2"  ["UserName"]=>  string(7) "abc@123"  ["Subject"]=>  string(15) "My Android Post"}
```

I need some thing like as shown below in a String array or a list:

```
1 abc@123 My Android Post
2 abc@123 My Android Post
```

How can I get only the value stored in the column in PHP. I am new to PHP scripts, so please help me in solving this issue.

My current PHP script is as shown below:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "iFocusBlogs";



$obtainedUserName = 1;         

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql="SELECT UID, UserName, Subject FROM AndroidTable WHERE Status ='" .$obtainedUserName. "'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
var_dump($obj);

 } 

$conn->close();
?>
```

Please let me know what change do I need to make in the script to get only the contents of the columns. All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

```
/* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1]).PHP_EOL;
    }
```

Try this **Updated**

```
$query="SELECT UID, UserName, Subject FROM AndroidTable WHERE Status ='" .$obtainedUserName. "'";

 if ($result = $conn->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row["UID"], $row["UserName"],$row["Subject"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Lot closer I got the below response:

1 (abc@123)2 (abc@123),  I am getting the value of columns getting repeated, and its displaying values of only one row. Can that be solved?

Comment: Very much there currently I am getting this response:

1 (abc@123) (My Android Post)2 (abc@123) (My Android Post), \n is not working, Can I know why?

Comment: for getting data of thired row use `printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row[1],$row[2]);`

Comment: I did not understand.

Comment: I am getting value of third column, but \n is not working, its not going to next line, after first row.

Comment: I am getting values properly, please tell me how make \n work after first row it is not going for the second line.

Comment: use `PHP_EOL` to break line

Comment: How to use that? I am not aware of the syntax of that and how to use it in my case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79092/discussion-between-saty-and-keshav1234).

Comment: Still didnt go to next line.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) instead of `fetch_object`. 
You might need some additional modifications to get the array exactly as you want, but at least it's a lot closer.

If you specify `MYSQL_NUM` as second parameter, you will get an array without keys and just numeric indexes. That array is clean enough to process further.

You can output the array using a for loop...

```
foreach($array as $item) {
  echo $item . '<br>';
}
```

or use `implode()`...

```
echo implode($array);
```

or use `json_encode()`...

```
echo json_encode($array);
```

It all depends how exactly you want to show your array.

Functions like `print_r` and `var_dump` are useful for inspecting the contents of arrays and other variables, but are unlikely to output that content in a format that is usable by external programs.

Comment: Trol I got the below response after I used fetch_array:

The value of the response is array(6) {  [0]=>  string(1) "1"  ["UID"]=>  string(1) "1"  [1]=>  string(7) "abc@123"  ["UserName"]=>  string(7) "abc@123"  [2]=>  string(15) "My Android Post"  ["Subject"]=>  string(15) "My Android Post"}array(6) {  [0]=>  string(1) "2"  ["UID"]=>  string(1) "2"  [1]=>  string(7) "abc@123"  ["UserName"]=>  string(7) "abc@123"  [2]=>  string(15) "My Android Post"  ["Subject"]=>  string(15) "My Android Post"}

Cant I remove that String(1) parts and ["  " ] parts?

Comment: The `[string(1)]` part is what you get when you use `var_dump`. You can use `print_r` to get a cleaner print, or you can just loop through the array and output it anyway you want. I've added a bit of extra info to the answer.. Anyway you will probably have to do *some* coding yourself, unless you can find a function that outputs it exactly as you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can access object `'->'` symbol

```
$tCont="";
while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
//var_dump($obj);
$tCont.='<tr><td>'.$obj->UID.'</td><td>'.$obj->UserName.'</td><td>'.$obj->Subject.'</td></tr>';

 } 
 echo $tCont;
```

Comment: Got the following response:

The value of the response is <tr><td>2</td><td>abc@123</td><td>My Android Post</td></tr>

Its giving me the value of second row and not both first row and second row. Is there a way to remove tr and td tags?

Comment: you can remove tr td if you don't want

Answer (score 1):

change your select statement, probably concatenate the columns:

```
$sql="SELECT CONCAT (UID,' ' , UserName,' ', Subject) AS myresult FROM AndroidTable WHERE Status =" . $obtainedUserName ;

$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

use fetch_assoc and print each row:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ 

echo $row['myresult'];

 }
```

Comment: got this error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in